# Best way to group every two elements from a slice?

Tags: sorting, go

Lets's say you have a slice of strings with letters like this inside:

`a b c d e f g h`

How would you iterate over the list and group every two elements together? I'm trying to save the first element in one variable and the next element in another variable.

This is what I am trying so far:

```golang
for i, str := range elem {
    first := i
    second := i + 1
    if second >= len(elem) {
        return
    }
}
```

This groups:

- a and b
- b and c
- c and d
- d and e
- e and f
- f and g

But how would I group

- a and b
- c and d
- e and f
- g and h

(every other grouping from the list above? I would rather not have to loop through that list and group every other but range over the slice and assemble in one go)

Comment: What exactly does it mean for you to "group"? A channel or a different slice? Output? In any case, just iterate in steps of two or skip every second iteration.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I would ideally like to return a variable that has the values needed, no need for another slice or channel. The user below did return results as a slice but returning each group one at a time would be better

Comment: When you `return`, the function (includitng the loop it's running currently) finishes. You could only get the first and second element, not multiple groups. I also don't understand how "sorting" comes into play then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes that's right, just would like a variable with the groups, not actually in a return statement that exits the loop. It's really a matter of grouping and not sorting.

Comment: I just modified the solution below to store `input[i-1]` and `input[i]` each in their own variable and that is the behavior I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, `for range` loop is a bad choice. Better use the "full form" of `for` loop

```
input := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}
result := make([]string, 0, len(input)/2)
for i := 1; i < len(input); i+=2 {
    result = append(result, input[i-1]+input[i])
}
fmt.Println(result)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0o53xr2tQlc